# Does the drive api have a limit on number of downloads at a time

Tags: google-drive-api

If i try to download multiple files from Google drive using the Rest API, after a while i start getting error,

The first one will be 
*BadRequest Bad request (400). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80190190)* 
and will get 
*RequestEntityTooLarge Request entity too large (413). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8019019D)* for all subsequent downloads.